# Estoy usando window.print para crear pdf, la duda es como puedo hacer para cambiar la posición de la paginacion que genera el navegador?

Tags: javascript, html

[image: Como puedo pasar ese 1/1 a la parte superior del documento]

Como puedo pasar ese 1/1 a la parte superior del documento

Comment: Recomendación: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 TL;DR? Edita la pregunta e incluye todo el código y descripción del escenario para que aumentes las chances de buenas respuestas. Saludos.

Comment: Y otra opción es utilizar una librería de generación directa del PDF. Hay varias dependiendo del lenguaje de programación que utilices, pero en general hay muy buenas opciones. Y así ya sabes el resultado final que tendrá el PDF resultante, en lugar de depender de parámetros que el usuario tenga en su navegador, interpretaciones de CSS, etc.

Answer (score 0):

No es posible, el tema del css para la imprimir es una de las tantas deudas que tiene la w3c con los desarrolladores.

Existen algunos borradores w3c para implementar mayor funcionalidad, pero no avanza. Te recomiendo usa la siguiente librería [paged.js](https://pagedjs.org/) la cual toma los elementos de esos borradores y los hace funcionar a modo de polyfill

Luego para cambiar de lugar el número de página sería algo como esto:

```
@page {


  @top-right-corner{
    content: counter(page);
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }

}
```